# Unable to set up the system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

> Initially, tank 1 contains $100$ liters of salted water with a concentration of $kg/l$. Tank 2 contains 100 liters of pure waters. Liquid pumps from tank $1$ to tank $2$ with a speed of $ l/m$, and from Tank 2 to 1 with the same speed. What is the concentration in tank 1 after 10 minutes?

**Attempt**

I was thinking that if we let $x_1:=$ concentration in tank 1 1, $x_2:=$ concentration in tank 2, then the system would be something like:

$$
\dot X= F(X),\quad X(0) = (1,0)^T
$$

Where $(1,0)$ denote the initial concentration of tank 1 and 2, but I couldn't figure out what should $F$ be (I don't need help solving the system, just setting it up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $X_i(t)=:X_i$ (kg)  the amount of salt in tank${}_i\>$, by $x_i$ (kg/l) the concentration of salt in tank${}_i\>$, and by $p$ (l/min) the amount of fluid pumped either way per minute. Using minutes as time unit we have
$$\eqalign{\dot X_1=-px_1+p x_2 \cr \dot X_2=px_1-p x_2\ .\cr}$$
Since $X_i=100 x_i$ at all times this amounts to
$$\eqalign{\dot x_1=-{p\over100}x_1+{p\over100} x_2 \cr \dot x_2={p\over100}x_1-{p\over100} x_2\ ,\cr}$$
with the initial conditions $x_1(0)=c$ (given), $x_2(0)=0$.

Comment: As best practice I would really recommend solving for mass (what you call $X$) and then dividing by the volume at the end to compute concentration (what you call $x$). There is little difference when the volume is constant, but it is helpful when the volume is not constant.